Nativewind styles are not executing in my react native application during build
I have a default react native application. I want to integrate Nativewind into my application. I followed the complete guide setup for Nativewind from their site. I am not changing some styling and non of it is implementing at all. I am not sure why but it is frustration. Can someone help me figure out how to edit the styling and have it convert and compile on my simulator.
App.tsx:
import React from 'react'
import { SafeAreaView, StatusBar, Text, View } from 'react-native'

function App(): React.JSX.Element {
  return (
    <View className='bg-slate-900'>
      <View className='flex-1 bg-black'>
        <StatusBar barStyle="light-content" translucent={false} backgroundColor={'black'} />
        <SafeAreaView className='flex-1 bg-red'>
          <Text className='text-bold'>Hello</Text>
        </SafeAreaView>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}

export default App

tailwind.config.js:
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: ["./App.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}", "./<custom-folder>/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}"],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
    colors: {
      transparent: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)',
      'white': '#ffffff',
      'purple': '#3f3cbb',
      'midnight': '#121063',
      'deep-slate': '#23272d',
      'deep-midnight': '#232431',
      'metal': '#565584',
      'tahiti': '#3ab7bf',
      'silver': '#ecebff',
      'bubble-gum': '#ff77e9',
      'bermuda': '#78dcca',
      'blanco': '#1d1e20'
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
}

package.json:
"nativewind": "^2.0.11",


custom-folder doesn't look like a real folder to me.
Replace this with the path where your source files are.
  content: [
    "./App.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}", 
    "./path-to-source-files/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}"],
  ]

